# Modal-Opener Inside fieldset/legend element

Tags: shopify, product, legend, variant, fieldset

On the Shopify product-page I want to display a Size-Chart.
Unfortunately I have way to less experience to get the text inside the  element.

This is the code which styles the elements like size and the variant picker for the customer to choose the size from

```
      {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
        <fieldset class="js product-form__input">
          <legend class="form__label">{{ option.name }}  </legend>    
           {% render 'product-variant-options', product: product, option: option, block: block %}
        </fieldset>
      {%- endfor -%}
```

and this is the code which currently "renders" the "Size-Chart" Popup.

```
            {%- when 'popup' -%}
              <modal-opener
                class="product-popup-modal__opener no-js-hidden quick-add-hidden"
                data-modal="#PopupModal-{{ block.id }}"
                {{ block.shopify_attributes }}
              >
                <button
                  id="ProductPopup-{{ block.id }}"
                  class="product-popup-modal__button link"
                  type="button"
                  aria-haspopup="dialog"
                >
                  {{ block.settings.text | default: block.settings.page.title }}
                </button>
              </modal-opener>
              <a href="{{ block.settings.page.url }}" class="product-popup-modal__button link no-js">
                {{- block.settings.text -}}
              </a>
```

This is how it currently looks on the page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izcA6.jpg)

You can see that the "Size-Chart" (German: Größentabelle) is way up there but  i want to bring it down on the same height as the "Größe" (Eng: Size) Text-Label and then to the right.

I tried to shorten the code and only render the class but it hasn´t worked yet